# Overlap Analysis of two rasters (heat maps) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, spatial-relationship

I would like to analyse two different heat maps I have created from point data and to understand areas where hot spots overlap with each other. To add a back story I need to understand the overlap of areas of high level fishing activity and the spatial occurrence of marine animal species. Is there any way I can perform this analysis in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: For raster , Spatial analyses are performs with Rastor calculator . In your case you could uses Vectors tools to make your spatials analyses.  Are you trying  to find the spatial correlation between fishing frequency and species population ?  Could you give more detail about it

Comment: Thanks for your response, I basically used the heat map plugin to create a map of high areas of vessel ping density with knots between 3-6 for beam and otter trawl activity. I have species by species data in points and i have used the heat map tool as well for this data and it would be nice to be able to get a numeric analysis of how much the high valued raster areas (high density) overlap with each other. Spatial correlation would be perfect.